# How to pass return value of method within class?

Tags: python, methods, initialization

What is the proper way to pass a returned value from a method within a class? Do you always call the method when needed or can the returned value be stored in the init method?
Let's say I have:

```
class Foo():

    def __init__(self):

    def heavy_method(self):
        #slow crunching
        return crunch

    def use_heavy_crunch(self):
        data = self.heavy_crunch()
        for i in data:
            #do data stuff
            #return data stuff

    def other_func_that_need_heavy_method(self):
        pass

d = Foo()
d.use_heavy_crunch()
```

**What I wonder is if above structure is the correct way or if the below way is equivalent or better?**

```
class Foo()

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None

    def heavy_method(self):
        #slow crunching
        self.data = crunch

    def use_heavy_crunch(self):
        for i in self.data:
            #do data stuff
            #return data stuff

    def other_func_that_need_heavy_method(self):
        pass

d = Foo()
d.heavy_method()
d.use_heavy_crunch()
```

So in the above example a method is called within an other method, while in the below example the return value of the method is passed to a variable in the init method and later on used in another function.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you're trying to do something like

```
class Foo():

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = self.heavy_method() # we assign the return value to an attribute of our object

    def heavy_method(self):
        #slow crunching
        return crunch

    def use_heavy_crunch(self):
        for i in self.data: # Notice it's now self.data
            #do data stuff
            #return data stuff

    def other_func_that_need_heavy_method(self):
        pass

d = Foo()
d.use_heavy_crunch()
```

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what I want to do, but not quite sure if it is "the proper way" to do things?

Comment: Probably, yes. If you know you will *always* want to use `self.data` it should be in the initialization. If you only sometimes use it....well then it depends on your implementation as to whether you favor saving memory, or saving computation power, as well as what is easiest for you to read/debug. Remember you don't need to save the variable too you can always call `d.use_heavy_crunch(d.heavy_method())` to supply the data. Again, it's what's most efficient not only for the computer but for the programmer to read as well.

Comment: I rely on `d.use_heavy_crunch()` to be able to load more data through over functions within the class. Thank you for pointing out the different aspects of the problem, the memory saving/computation power didn't occur to my. I tend to only see slow-bad, good-fast. Thank you for the insights!

Comment: @MisterButter Assuming you have the CPU and memory to handle it, you can always implement multithreading/multiprocessing to speed things up assuming they can be run in parallel. If you're worried about speed you can also try different implementations and time the results of several runs with each setup. Typically it's not wise to optimize for speed until your code works first though...

Comment: That is very true, the only way to get a speed increase is in my case by multithreading/multiprocessing since the time consuming processes are requests made to api, and not lacking computer power, (still a 2012 Mac, nothing fancy).

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the initialization method of class to perform heavy processing tasks, its generally bad practice, the class initialization should only be used to initialize class based instance variable.
If you are planning to call `d.use_heavy_crunch()` multiple times in future after the instance `d` is created and the return value of `d.heavy_method()` did not change over time then the second approach is good way to go, as in case of first approach every time you call `d.use_heavy_crunch()` you are calling `d.heavy_method()` and performing the same tasks repeatedly. In the second approach you would only call `d.heavy_method()` once and later use its result in other methods of class.

Comment: I see, thank you for the valuable insights and for being on point!